# Reference in understanding NCPDP D.0

Tags: standards

I have am working on a Health care project and have come across  NCPDP D.0 standard, although I have googled and found some basic information on wiki and other sites, I was looking are there any simple reference or open source example of software allowing pharmacy transactions in NCPDP D.0 format.

Has anyone in the community worked/working on this, and if they can share some information it would be of gr8 help.

Thanks,
HSR.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will be hard pressed to find any public documentation or open source software following this standard. I haven't been able to find it myself, and to gain access to the standard it's my understanding that you will need to be a member of [NCPDP](http://www.ncpdp.org/membership_signup.aspx). This is a $675 bump and you are not allowed to share the standard outside of your organization. [Standards Purchase](http://www.ncpdp.org/standards_purchase.aspx).

In addition you'll also need the X12 5010 standard. On the [X12 store](http://store.x12.org/store/healthcare-5010-consolidated-guides) this could set you back a few thousand dollars.

In any event, the documentation though incomplete is decent on the [NCPDP.ORG](http://www.ncpdp.org/) site, you should check it out.